# GNU Make Under Windows: Check for cygwin in PATH

Tags: windows, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

I have been putting together a makefile in a Windows environment for my team to use. I decided to use MinGW's version of make for Windows. I put that executable with its dependencies into a repository location that should be in everyone's PATH variable. The executable was renamed "make.exe" for simplicity.

Then I realized that I have to account for the case when someone has cygwin's bin folder in their path. Commands like echo, rmdir, and mkdir will call echo.exe, rmdir.exe, and mkdir.exe from cygwin's bin folder. This means that I need to appropriately catch this scenario and use different flags for each command.

I see three cases here:

1. Cygwin's bin path comes before the path where make.exe is located in the repository. When a team member executes make.exe, they will be executing cygwin's make. Unix-style commands must be used.
2. Cygwin's bin path comes after the path where make.exe is located in the repository. The correct make.exe will be executed, but I still have to use Unix-style commands.
3. Cygwin is not installed or not in the PATH. I can use all Windows commands in this case.

I am fine with treating cases 1 and 2 the same. Since MinGW's make and cygwin's make are both based on GNU Make, then I don't see this being much of an issue other than incompatibility issues between versions of GNU Make. Let's just assume that isn't a problem for now.

I have come up with the following check in my makefile.

```
ifneq (,$(findstring cygdrive,$(PATH))$(findstring cygwin,$(PATH))$(findstring Cygwin,$(PATH)))
    #Use Unix style command variables
else
    #Use Windows style command variables
endif
```

Finding "cygdrive" in the path variable means that we are most likely in case 1. Finding "cygwin" or "Cygwin" in the path variable most likely means that we are in case 2. Not finding either string in the path most likely means that we are in case 3.

I am not completely fond of this solution because the cygwin's folder can be renamed or the string "cygwin" or "cygdrive" can be put in the PATH variable without having cygwin installed. One team member is still having issues as he has cygwin's bin path in the PATH variable, but the above does not catch that. I am assuming that he renamed the folder to something else, but I haven't been able to check on that.

So is there a better way to figure out what syntax that I should be using?

Comment: A coworker gave me a different workaround which doesn't answer this question, but solves my problem. If I execute "cmd.exe /C WindowsCommandHere" then it will execute the windows shell command before an exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cygwin make v. MinGW make: Does mingw make support the jobserver, as in can you do `make -j5`? If not, `${.FEATURES}` has `jobserver` for cygwin make. Maybe `load` is a good test too.

Cygwin before non-cygwin on path: `cygpath.exe` is unique to cygwin. You could just look for this in `${PATH}`. Unfortunately, Windows users like using spaces in folder names, and there's no way of dealing with this in pure make. `$(shell which make)` will return `/usr/bin/make` for cygwin, though a shell invocation on every make run is very smelly.

You don't install a compiler from a repository, is not `make` a similar case? Just get your users to install cygwin and be done with it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe features can be added or removed from version to version. I'm not too fond of that.
 
$(shell which make) looks promising. I can do "$(shell which make || (echo F))" If that returns F then the command failed and I can use Windows commands (because Windows uses "where" instead of "which"). If it passes, I can further evaluate what it returns. Like you said, it will return "/usr/bin/make" if I am using cygwin's make (case 1) or something else if I am using another make (case 2).

Comment: In the end, yes you are correct that tools should not be located in a repository.

Comment: @Talis86 Wow, I didn't know about `where`, TVM! (I had been using a `cmd` one-liner that uses nested `for` loops.)

Comment: Actually, since mingw make is a windows program, won't it import PATH in windows format? [Your looking for `cygdrive` in `$PATH` check might be better using `$(filter /cygdrive/%,$(subst :, ,${PATH}))` BTW]

Comment: It will actually only format the path for /cygdrive/ if it is executing cygwin's make (case 1). If a different make is being executed, even if cygwin is still in the PATH variable, then PATH will not be formatted.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution that I thought up.

```
ifeq (a,$(shell echo "a"))
    #Use Unix style command variables
else
    #Use Windows style command variables
endif
```

This is based on the fact that 'echo "a"' in Unix will print a (without quotes) but windows will print "a" (with the quotes). If I am using the Unix style echo then I can assume that I am using all Unix commands.

I don't find this solution very elegant though, so I am not marking it as the solution for this question. I think this is better than what I originally had though.