# Is there any way to see the output of a shell script when launched through make, for SAM

Tags: python, makefile, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to build a multi-layer Python SAM (AWS Serverless Application Model) app.

Nothing too fancy, but it has some dependencies, which are managed using `pipenv`.

SAM has a `sam build` command which behind the scenes uses make.
I have a `Makefile` that looks like this:

```
# Empty build target for "sam build". Why?
# 1. "sam build Layers" works
# 2. "sam build" for the main function doesn't (it tries to use pip and crashes)
# With this empty target the main build is skipped and only the layers are built, which is enough.
build-Function: ;

build-Layers:
    bash pip-install.sh "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)"
```

`pip-install.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ARTIFACTS_DIR="${1}"

set -eu

# Detect Cygwin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20691293/1320143
uname="$(uname -s)"
if [[ "${uname}" =~ "Cygwin" ]]
then
    # AWS SAM for Windows passes a Windows path Cygwin tools (make, etc.) don't understand.
    ARTIFACTS_DIR="$(cygpath -u "${ARTIFACTS_DIR}")"
fi

PROJECT_PATH="$(echo "${ARTIFACTS_DIR}" | sed 's@/.aws-sam.*@@')"
PIPFILE_PATH="$(echo "${ARTIFACTS_DIR}" | sed 's@/.aws-sam.*@/../Pipfile.lock@' | xargs readlink -f)"

mkdir -p "${ARTIFACTS_DIR}/python"
# We're using pipenv, which does not use requirements.txt.
# requirements.txt is used by SAM to automatically package and deploy layers (dependencies).
# To avoid dependency/version duplication, we extract the info from the pipenv info.

jq -r '.default | to_entries[] | .key + .value.version' "${PIPFILE_PATH}" > requirements.txt

# For debugging purposes.
ls -lha

python -m pip install -r "${PROJECT_PATH}/requirements.txt" -t "${ARTIFACTS_DIR}/python"
```

The important part is that this project uses `pipenv` to manage dependencies, not `pip`, and SAM uses `make` as the build tool but after that, it only has a `pip` extension. This script basically creates a dependency list that `pip` understands and then `pip` downloads all the dependencies in a folder, which will then be packaged as a big layer.

**The main issue is debugging.**

I've seen that for some (IMHO dumb) reason `make` hides the output of shell scripts it launches. Supposedly `make` can be tricked to show it, with this: [See output of shell script in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021245/see-output-of-shell-script-in-makefile)

I've tried it and it doesn't work. I run `sam build Layers` and I only see the `sam` output. I've tried `--debug`, same thing.

Is there a way to show that output? I want to be able to debug the script in the `make`/`sam build` context as I don't understand some errors I'm getting

Comment: "make" does not hide output of shell scripts it launches. If output does not show, it has been redirected elsewhere.

Comment: ... which would be a function either of the makefile in use or of the program that runs `make`.

Comment: Well, that's why I'm here, this is not strictly a `make` issue, it's also a `sam build` issue.

The makefile doesn't redirect anything, neither does the script it launches. So in my opinion it must be `sam build`, I just want to find out if there is any way to avoid this.

Comment: @Jens how do you explain this answer, then? See the top voted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11021891/1320143 Based on testing, make definitely doesn't show command output from the script, without any redirection happening. You have to go out of your way to change that, and *redirect* the output to stderr to actually see it.

Comment: @oblio The explanation is that `$(shell xxx)` is not a make thing. It's a GNU make thing and especially designed to expand to the output of a command. This can't go to the terminal by definition.

Comment: I was using `bash pip-install.sh "$(ARTIFACTS_DIR)"` before and that didn't work either. Is that a GNUism, too? 

Answer (score -3, accepted):

At re:Invent 2020, AWS announced that Lambda can now use Docker images.

Instead of using the mix of Make and proprietary setup SAM provides for building Lambda layers, just use standard Dockerfiles and save a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

It's not `make` that is hiding the output, it's `sam` ([issue #2006](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2006)). When `make` fails (returning any exit code different from 0), it only prints STDERR. You can use shell redirection to redirect STDOUT to STDERR:

```
my-rule:
    npm run build-my-lambda 1>&2
```